# 401k benefits meaning: 10% of salary deferral subject to first 0.6% of compensation as elective contribution

Tags: united-states, 401k, contribution

From the benefits package of a prospective employer:

> CompanyX contribution: 10% of salary deferral subject to first 0.6% of
>   compensation as elective contribution

What does this mean?

Comment: That's a darned good question!  **Did you ask HR?**

Comment: @RonJohn, I'm not in contact with HR yet, but I will if I can :)